# HTML5 tags in .xhtml extension file

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a bunch of xhtml files with content like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

</html>
```

I am planning to use HTML5.

1) Can HTML5 content be saved in a .xhtml file without any issues with specific browsers? Its not the question of just changing the file extensions. The server runtime we are using, does special processing for .xhtml files. If we change the extension to html, the server runtime will try to process all plain html files too.

2) Is following acceptable in HTML5?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

</html>
```

(that is, HTML5 doctype and xml namespaces)

Comment: File extension doesn't matter for the browser.

Comment: HTML5 is not a valid XML format (it can contain 'unclosed' tags, etc), so the `<?xml` header could cause you problems, even if you're using the HTML5 doctype. But this is speculation because I've never actually written code with this combination. One thing is for sure, though; the W3C validator will baulk at that mixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can HTML5 content be saved in a .xhtml file without any issues with
>   specific browsers?

Providing your server is configured to serve ,xhtml files with a media type of `text/html`, then yes. It probably does, because otherwise your .xhtml files would not work with IE8 or earlier. But if it serves with either a `application/xml` or `application/xhtml+xml` media type, then you should use [XHTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) markup. (You may also find that your markup needs to be XHTML5 compliant for your server side special .xhtml file processing to continue to work correctly.)

> Is following acceptable in HTML5?

It's not *valid* HTML5, but then your first snippet is not valid XHTML 1.0 either. It won't cause any new problems treating it as HTML5.